Old animation with orange underground goblins and a scared boy
I have memories about this animation movie, from maybe 15-20 years ago, where there were these orange goblins (or some kind of creatures), living underground and they were coming out during the night. The main character was a boy. One night he was walking on some road and there were trees on both sides. He was scared, he was sure there are goblins between the trees watching him and moving around, but the boy remembered that he was advised to sing songs when going out at night and nothing bad will happen to him. So he started singing and skipping while walking and indeed nothing happened and the creatures disappeared. That's all i remember about the plot - the lesson was to sing songs when you are scared. The whole movie was in orange-red (like fire) colors and dark-green-blue for the nights scenes. 

15-20 years sounds a lot, but when you do the math it still is somewhere around the year 200 ;)
Do you remember the origin of movie, i.e its country, language etc?

Well, at least I'm sure it wasn't a japanese anime. Maybe it was European, but I'm not sure because it was with Bulgarian dubbing. :) And since i'm 26 y/o already, and when i watched it i was little ... I assume It might have been around 15-16 years ago - maximum of 20 :) I asked so many people from my childhood and none remember it .. i start doubting if it's real :D

"The Princess and the Goblin" fits some of this, but not quite enough for me to be sure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_and_the_Goblin_(film)

@ping , this is totally it! I guess my memories evolved with the time, you're right - it doesn't really fit the explanation I gave. Anyways, if you want - write it as an answer and i will accept it :)

I've written up an answer. Funnily enough, the thing that stuck in my head about this film was that the goblins have sensitive feet, and you can beat them by jumping on their toes. Before the internet became so ubiquitous I had an urge to try and remember what "that film with the goblins with sensitive feet" was every so often. The importance of singing wasn't something  I remembered. If we were both looking for the film at the same time, we might not even have recognised each other's descriptions!

The description reminded me of the film "The Princess and the Goblin" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_and_the_Goblin_(film) and http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107875/
The scene described in the question sounds a bit like the beginning of the film:
Wiki:

When sun sets, Irene is lost in a sinister forest, and is attacked
  when a clawed hands bursts through the earth and attempts to seize her
  kitten, Turnip. Several deformed animals corner the frightened
  Princess, until a strange singing sounds through the trees, driving
  them into a fit, and they flee. The singing is revealed to be a young
  boy, Curdie, the son of a miner. He discovers Irene is lost, and leads
  her back to the castle. He informs her that the monsters were goblins
  and their "pets", and that they are driven away by singing.

I don't remember it being particularly orange, but from Google images, there are at least a few orangey scenes that might have stuck in your mind...
